# Canvas-map, invisible right border forcing other div below it

Tags: html, css, canvas, maps

My google map canvas, is set to width 80%. The map itself fills 80%, but there's a wide space to the right of the canvas that fills the 20% left of the screen.

Which makes my div unable to be placed there.

html:

```
<div id="map-canvas" ></div>

<div id="search">Test</div>

css:

  #map-canvas {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    min-height: 80px;
    min-width: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
  }



#search {
 background: #2E2E2E;
 float: right;
 width: 20%;
 height: 800px;
 z-index: 1;

 }
```

Comment: So, you want the #map-canvas and #search vertically beside each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because a `div` is by default a `block` element, which means it fills all the width available for it, unless you tell otherwise.

One way is to use `float`, that "disables" the `block` property. You tried using it on the search div, but the map div is your problem.

Add a `float:left` property to the map div and it will do. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/L222L/1/

**Just a tip:**

What's the point of setting a margin property, if you are then removing it?

```
margin-left: 50px;  <---
margin-right: 50px;   <---
/* ... */
margin: 0;   <---
```

Comment: I was trying alot of stuff to see if it worked, and that margin paradox was created. It is ofcourse a bad mistake :) Thanks alot for the help it worked!